# How to install virtio balloon driver in Windows Server 2008 Std x64

Tags: windows-server-2008, kvm-virtualization

I am trying to run the install command in the INF file that comes on the virtio drivers ISO, after having downloaded devcon.exe from Microsoft's website. I am getting the following error and I don't know how to progress;

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ADM64>devcon install BALLOON.inf PCI\VEN_1AF4&DEV_1002&SUBSYS_00051AF4&REV_00
devcon.exe failed.
'DEV_1002' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'SUBSYS_00051AF4' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'REV_00' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [Virtio](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/WindowsGuestDrivers/Download_Drivers) drivers for Windows 7/2008/2012.
"devcon" is not necessary to execute.

Answer (score 1):

```
devcon install BALLOON.inf "PCI\VEN_1AF4&DEV_1002&SUBSYS_00051AF4&REV_00"
```

Comment: That is exactly what I have written above as not working?

Comment: The difference is that @mlaci has quoted the parameter due to the presence of shell command characters. An unescaped or unquoted ampersand splits the command line into multiple commands, executed in sequence. The post would make more sense if this rationale is mentioned.

Comment: Well spotted, but it didn't help.